# DES P box design criteria

Tags: des

I hope somebody can help me to find out how DES P box has designed. I am doing DES by hand so I want to know how these numbers are arranged?

Comment: Did you have a look at [this question / answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/20875/1172)? It does seem to contain some references in the question.

Comment: I want  know how elements of PC-2 are selected. I have seen the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21717596/generating-des-subkeys-from-64b-master-key

Comment: but how key tab b and key tab s is created is still not clear to me