# Does the encryption algorithm DES perform random permutations? If so how is information not lost?

Tags: des, permutation

> Before round 1 begins, all 64 bits of an incoming message and all 56 bits of the secret key are separately permuted (shuffled)

My question is this : Is the shuffling of the bits performed randomly? If it is performed randomly then how does the reciever decrypt the message successfully even though he/she does not know the order in which the shuffling was carried out (since the shuffling was performed randomly and the only information known to the reciever is only the key and nothing else)?

Comment: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-are-the-benefits-of-the-two-permutation-tables-in-des

Comment: So the permutations are not carried out at random but are instead performed in a specifc order so as to make HW implementations easier to design. I think i got it... Thanks. :-)