# Learning about Feistel Cipher

Tags: block-cipher, stream-cipher, feistel-network

[image]I'm learning about Feistel Ciphers at the moment, but having issues with the formulae, so I can't move on from it.

Encryption:

1. $_{+1} = _$
2. $_{+1} = _ \oplus ( _ , _)$

For the round function $( _ , _)$, could someone advise on what exactly I need to do? Let's say my key is $1197$, what needs to happen in between the brackets, $(_ , _)$ , full diagram screenshot attached, thanks.[image]

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. I've edited your question, please check. The round function which is usually called the $F$ function performs confusion and diffusion. What is your actual question? Normally, one must define it as in [DES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard#The_Feistel_(F)_function)

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. So If I have a plaintext and divide it into 2 parts, left and right, I need to put the right side through the round function. This should get me my value to XOR with the left side, but i'm not sure what exactly I have to do with the right side and round function in the 1st place.

Comment: Yes, this is what the 1. and 2. equations already says. What is the problem? Did you see this [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/39927/what-is-the-definition-of-feistel-cipher)?

Comment: Yes I checked he link you supplied but I can't really make sense of it. As I said Im only learning about it now, so still a bit raw with how it works. I did find something on a video from another site, it seems to imply that I must XOR the right side with Key. From here I would shift this value by 1 it and XOR it with the left side, does that sound correct? I have added a screenshot of this above.

Comment: It is necessary to distinguish between on one hand Feistel cipher that is a structure or a tool that is used to construct block ciphers, on the other hand concrete applications of this tool. So $F$ is a function that takes two inputs, it could be any function but requirements are that it provides confusion and diffusion. The output of $F$ is then xored with the other part of the input. It might be worth mentioning that the keys $K_i$ are generated by some other procedures form input key.Now if you want to see a concrete implementation of $F$ then look at $DES$ for example.

Comment: You are using too simplified $F$ function. That is already insecure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it makes more sense if you write the two equations like this (referring to the nice [diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher) in Wikipedia):
$$L_{i+1}=R_i,\; R_{i+1}=L_i\oplus F_{K_i}(R_i).$$
In each round, the round function $F$ takes as input the corresponding round key $K_i$ and the previous round's right output, then computes the output value, which is then XORed with the previous round's left output. 
$F$ is usually modeled as a pseudorandom function and has many instantiations (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher#List_of_Feistel_ciphers) for a list of Feistel ciphers, of which each specifies its own $F$ instantiation and key schedule).
This [post](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/60502/31422) discusses the requirements/goals for good $F$ instantiations.

Comment: Thanks for this, makes much more sense to me now. My maths is a bit rusty! This [link](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/60502/what-are-the-requirements-from-a-round-function-in-feistel-network) is also very helpful with explaining what key I should use, thank you.

Comment: @terodee One answer to that link mentioned the key schedule, but it seems for SPNs rather than Feistel ciphers. The key schedules are also specified in the listed [Feistel cipher instantiations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher#List_of_Feistel_ciphers).

Answer (score 1):

Function $F(x)$ should be function with pseudo-random output (if you change 1 bit in input there should be a chance to change half of output bits). There is no need to use a bijection, because in schema we do not need $F^{-1}(x)$.

Idea behind a Feistel Network is to use some function to hide bits of input behind pseudo-random outputs (but predictable).